# Eigen: how to speed up a += coeffs * coeffs.transpose()

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I need to compute many (about 400k) solutions of small linear least square problems. Each problem contains 10-300 equations with only 7 variables. 
To solve these problems i use eigen library. Straight solving takes too much time and i transform each problem to solving 7x7 system of linear equations by deriving derivatives by my hand.

I recieve nice speed-up but i want to increase performance again.

I use vagrind to profile my program and i found that operation with highest self cost is operator += of eigen matrix. This operation takes more than ten calls of a.ldlt().solve(b);

I use this operator to compose A matrix and B vector of each system of equations

```
//I cal these code to solve each problem
const int nVars = 7;
//i really need double precision
Eigen::Matrix<double, nVars, nVars> a = Eigen::Matrix<double, nVars, nVars>::Zero();
Eigen::Matrix<double, nVars, 1> b = Eigen::Matrix<double, nVars, 1>::Zero();
Eigen::Matrix<double, nVars, 1> equationCoeffs;
//............................
//Somewhere in big cycle.
//equationCoeffs and z are updated on each iteration
a += equationCoeffs * equationCoeffs.transpose();
b += equationCoeffs * z;
```

Where z is some scalar

So my question is: How can i improve performance of these operations?

PS Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 3):

Instead of forming the matrix and vector components of the normal equation by hand, one equation at a time, you might try to allocate a large enough matrix once (e.g. 300 x 7) to store all coefficients and then let Eigen's optimized matrix-matrix product kernels do the job for you:

```
Matrix<double,Dynamic,nbVars> D(300,nbVars);
VectorXd f(300);
for(...)
{
  int nb_equations = ...;
  for(i=0..nb_equations-1)
  {
    D.row(i) = equationCoeffs;
    f(i) = z;
  }
  a = D.topRows(nb_equations).transpose() * D.topRows(nb_equations);
  b = D.topRows(nb_equations).transpose() * f.head(nb_equations);
  // solve ax=b
}
```

You might bench with both a column-major and row-major storage for the matrix `D` to see which one is best.

Another possible approach would be to declare `a`, `equationCoeffs`, and `b` as 8x8 or 8x1 matrix or vectors making sure that `equationCoeffs(7)==0`. This way you maximize SIMD usage. Then use `a.topLeftCorners<7,7>()`, `b.head<7>()` when calling LDLT. You might even combine this strategy with the previous one.

Finally, if your CPU support AVX or FMA, you might use the devel branch and compile with `-mavx` or `-mfma` to get a significant speedup.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Looks very interesting. I will try approach with huge matrices. Also I tried to use 8x8/8 x 1 matrices before but it gives me no speedup.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use g++5.1, you might want to take a look at OpenMP
( http://openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.Examples.pdf ).
G++5.1 (or gcc5.1 for C) also has some basic support for OpenACC, you can try that as well. There should be more implementation of OpenACC in the future.

Also if you have access to intel compiler (icc, icpc) it speeded up my code even just by using it.

If you can use nvidia's nvcc, you might use the thrust library
( http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#axzz3g8xJPGHe ), there's a lot of sample code on their github as well
( https://github.com/thrust/thrust ). However, using thrust is not so straight forward and needs some real thinking.

EDIT:
Thrust also requires Nvidia GPU.
For AMD cards I believe there is a library called ArrayFire, which looks very similar to Thrust (I have not tried that one, yet)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have no access to advanced compilers like icc. But maybe i will try to use openmp. Also i think that is possible to use openmp with old version of gcc

Answer (score 0):

I have a single problem Ax=b with 480k float variables. The matrix A is sparse and solving it with Eigen BiCGSTAB took 4.8 seconds.

I also worked with ViennaCL before, so I tried to solve the same problem there, and it took only 1.2 seconds. The increase in spead is realised
by the processing on the GPU.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i have many very small dense problems not one big and sparse. Also i cannot use GPU now =(